Did I actually upgrade?
I am Kubuntu . I got a prompt to upgrade to 22.04.01
I left it there for few hours, eventually I clicked on it and it reported an error.
I restarted my laptop but I am not getting the upgrade prompt back.
Is there a way to launch the prompt to upgrade to 22.04.01?
UPDATE
After a couple of restarts I got the prompt to install I clicked on it and it mentioned 24.04.05 LTS Noble Numbat.
I went through the installation and the system does look different but I still see in the about system 24.04
So what exactly happened?

Did you fix the problem that caused the first error? Restarting does not fix many types of problems.

@user535733: there was no error message. After a second restart it showed a prompt to upgrade to 24.04 24.04 LTS 'Noble Numbat'. I did the upgrade but I see in the setting in about systems 24.04 so I am not sure what was the upgrade I just did

@user535733: I updated the post

Defaults are not changed in Ubuntu upgrades
Upgrading Ubuntu, due example from 22.04 to 24.04, does not change any defaults including the wallpaper. So it looks the same. Don't worry. You are now using 24.04.
If you want to use the new wallpapers or the new Gnome Text Editor app you will have to select one of the new wallpapers or set up the new text editor as the default.
More Information
Upgrade from 22.04 to 22.04.1 (and subsequently 22.04.4 to 22.04.5) are automatic. These are called point releases. They happen in the course of updating your system. You don't have to do anything for these upgrades. Before upgrade to 24.04.1, your computer must have been at 22.04.4/5.
See What is the significance of Ubuntu version numbers?
When you thought you were upgrading from 22.04 to 22.04.1, you must have started upgrading to 24.04.1. All 24.04, 24.04.1 etc. are LTS. You can see this by visiting the official Ubuntu download website.
Hope this helps

I am confused what happened. I wanted to go from 22.04LTS to 22.04.01LTS. I  ended up with 24.04 which is not LTS. What does that mean? Why did it happen? I am confused. I pressed a prompt that said LTS but apparently what was mentioned int he prompt was wrong?

Thank you for explaining. Doesn't the system display the information about this kind of path? I wasn't expecting that this would happen. Its like I accept a prompt for X version and in the end go all the way up to Z without any heads up

I did get that but it still did not mention the full upgrade path

This is the window I get for upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.1 for Ubuntu. You can follow along with screenshots at https://ostechnix.com/upgrade-to-ubuntu-24-04-lts-desktop/
